# Drupal commerce update to 1.14 from 1.13 - breaks checkout screen

Tags: commerce

I have also a different problem with commerce update with latest 1.14 version. After update via drush, order created and it reached checkout:shipping step, but when I do final order confirmation step, it stuck at payment page [checkout:payment] step, it shows blank page, actually I've skipped the checkout payment step on my previous 1.13 version and it worked fine.

what will be the issue? how to track drupal page and functions execution?

Comment: Can you check recent logs(Drupal Side) or apache error log?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for anyone to diagnose the issue with the information given. A blank page typically means a PHP error has interrupted the page request. When you encounter situations like this, look to your PHP / Apache error logs to see what clues is gives you.

I'm not aware of anything in the Commerce 1.14 release that should cause the checkout form to suddenly break, but perhaps it's related to some other contributed module on your site. If you track it down to a core problem that you can reproduce on a clean install of Commerce Kickstart 1.x, feel free to open a bug report in the Drupal Commerce issue queue.